# Cannot register simple-history if already using ModelAdmin customization?

Tags: django, django-modeladmin, django-simple-history

register() only takes 3 positional arguments ("self" being passed implicitly. If already using a ModelAdmin class to customize the appearance of the model in Django Admin, my registration would look like:

```
admin.site.register(AttorneyGroup, AttorneyGroupAdmin)
```

If I want to register SimpleHistoryAdmin, I would be adding a 4th positional argument, like so:

```
admin.site.register(AttorneyGroup, AttorneyGroupAdmin, SimpleHistoryAdmin)
```

This raises the following exception:

```
TypeError: register() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

It seems that simple-history cannot be registered if the user is already customizing the model using ModelAdmin. Is there another way to implement simple-history that avoids this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
class AttorneyGroupAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):
      #custom admin

admin.site.register(AttorneyGroup, AttorneyGroupAdmin)
```

This allows you to use the Simple History Admin while still customizing it however you'd like

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of these in separate register functions if you wanted to:

```
admin.site.register(AttorneyGroup)
admin.site.register(AttorneyGroupAdmin)
admin.site.register(SimpleHistoryAdmin)
```

**Edit:**

You are correct in your comment. My original code was to show that you don't need to do every model in one line. I should have been more accurate. You can do this instead:

```
from .models import AttorneyGroup, SimpleHistory

admin.site.register(AttorneyGroup, AttorneyGroupAdmin)
admin.site.register(SimpleHistory, SimpleHistoryAdmin)
```

Comment: the register() function takes 3 positional arguments, 

`def register(self, model_or_iterable, admin_class=None, **options):`

As I understand, if I separated AttorneyGroup from AttorneyGroupAdmin, it would just treat AttorneyGroup as though I didn't specify a ModelAdmin class for it. So I wouldn't be able to apply the customizations that AttorneyGroupAdmin makes.